# Ruby: Add a variable to translation key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation

I need to add a variable in a translation key in a view of a Ruby on Rails project (not in the value, in the key). Ex, this is my key:

```
= t 'services.categories.website_html'
```

What I need to do is that the word "website" from that key comes from a variable named `"category.className"`

I have tryed this, with no results:

```
= t 'services.categories.#{category.className}_html'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of simple quotes ;)

```
= t "services.categories.#{category.className}_html"
```

Strings are not interpolated inside single quotes, but they are in double quotes.